# Upgrade OpenSSL on Docker php:7.2-apache to connect to smtp.gmail

Tags: php, docker, openssl, gmail, debian

Using the official Docker php:7.2-apache image, we moved our Symfony 4.2 application to containers.
We then had a first problem with (seemingly) OpenSsl with our Database Connection (SQL Server ODBC 17).

```
SQLSTATE [08001, 10054]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746
SQLSTATE [08001, 10054]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection
```

Our original server runned on Ubuntu 20.04 with Openssl 1.1.1f for PHP and the Docker image is on Debian 10 with Openssl 1.1.1d 2019 (installed by default).
So I installed the 1.1.1f version manually ( since the last stable avalaible on the package repo is 1.1.1d )

```
RUN rm /usr/bin/openssl
RUN cd /usr/local/src && wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1f.tar.gz && tar -xf openssl-1.1.1f.tar.gz
RUN cd /usr/local/src/openssl-1.1.1f && ./config && make && make install
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl && ldconfig
```

And the connection to the Database worked **BUT** we now can't connect SwiftMailer to our gmail account.

```
Swift_TransportException: Connecn could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

This gmail connection worked with OpenSSL 1.1.1d - so I checked and discovered that PHP still use the 1.1.1d as the Header library

```
OpenSSL support => enabled
OpenSSL Library Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1f  2020
OpenSSL Header Version => OpenSSL 1.1.1d  2019
```

So my thoughts and questions, about OpenSSL :

- I've found that to update the Header however, PHP must be recompilled
  and using the officiel Docker php:7.2-apache image, I am not sure how
  to proceed ( or if it is even a good idea to begin with). How should I proceed ?
- I am not sure it is due to this problem and will try with a more recent
  version of the library - 1.1.1i ( or newer )
- I might,as a last resort, change my base image to ubuntu:20.04 and manually install PHP but I feel like it might be Overkill - and would cost lot of time. Would that be worth it ?

Both email and database connection must works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended up reverting back to 1.1.1d and applied this fix here

https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/issues/1021
From the issue :

> This is a workaround for now:
>
> Modify /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf config file as follows (fyi see known
> issues with OpenSSL 1.1.1 in Debian 10):
>
> Change the last line from CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2 to
> CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1
>
> I can connect to SQL Server 2017 or 2014 without the need to downgrade
> OpenSSL.

There's an applicable Dockerfile snippet for it too.

```
RUN apt-get update -yqq \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends openssl \
    && sed -i -E 's/(CipherString\s*=\s*DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=)2/\11/' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

**Caution though** as it may open security issues (also mentionned in the github link)